# Redirect only from homepage using regex and preserving UTM parameters

Tags: regex, wordpress

I am trying to redirect all mobile traffic that goes to the homepage of a website to the mobile version of the homepage and preserve the UTM parameters. I'm using the wordpress plugin [Redirection](https://redirection.me/) which allows regex to be used.

Currently what is happening is:

www.website.com/?utm_source=test  ->  www.website.com/mobile/

which causes the UTM tags not to fire and google analytics not to register the website click.

I want two different things to happen. If a user goes to the homepage (and only the homepage) it should be redirect to the /mobile page. And, if a user clicks on a link to the homepage with UTM parameters, the user should also be redirected to the /mobile page as well but the UTM parameters should be preserved.

So like this:

www.website.com/?utm_source=test  ->  www.website.com/mobile/?utm_source=test

www.website.com/  ->  www.website.com/mobile/

I tried to use regex like this:

Source URL = ^/(.*) 
 Matched target = /mobile$1

But this redirects traffic from all pages to the /mobile page, not just traffic to the homepage.

Is there a way to achieve this using this plugin with regex or is there a better solution out there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing the redirection plugin you mention is at release version 3.7.3.

It appears the functionality you are after ("Pass query parameters from source to target") is available in 4.0 alpha.
https://redirection.me/2019/01/redirection-3-7-beta-and-4-0-alpha/

Consider testing the alpha / beta pre-release version or use an alternative redirection method for the functionality you desire.

You might find that a newer version 4.0 is available from Github rather that the WordPress.org site - without the need to use Alpha or Beta releases.

The latest Redirection plugin releases can be found here:
https://github.com/johngodley/redirection/releases